# Installing python-crfsuite to anaconda

Tags: python, crf, python-crfsuite

I downloaded pythoncrfsuite package from

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-crfsuite

and installed it via

```
python setup.py install
```

command and it installed perfectly on the system. However, I'm not able to use it with spyder, whever I import pycrfsuite I get this following error, can you provide me with an appropriate solution for the same?

```
import pycrfsuite
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "pycrfsuite/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
from ._pycrfsuite import *
ImportError: No module named _pycrfsuite
```

Despite that there is a file named _pycrfsuite.cpp in the folder containing __init_.py.

Comment: Does spyder use the same python Interpreter as the one with which you executed `python setup.py install`?

Comment: I posted this question long time back. I don't recall everything now regarding your question, however I did manage to get it working at that time. I will upload the solution ASAP.